# Beginner python functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, programming-languages, python-3.6

So dumb question, but in the code below the guess_compare function is failing (I think because it can’t refer to the inputs ‘guess’ and ‘game word’. Any insights on how to fix? Code below:

```
import random

max_guesses=1
guess=""
game_word=""

def word_gen():
    potential_guesses=["hello", "test", "never"]
list_length=int(len(potential_guesses))

 game_word=potential_guesses[random.randint(1-1,list_length-1)]
    print (game_word)

def guesser():
   guess=input("give a letter...")
   print(guess)

def guess_compare():
    if guess==game_word[0]:
        print("correct")
    else:
        print("wrong")

guess_compare()
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate to us that its failing with an exception / traceback?

Comment: @JacobIRR picture below

Comment: @JacobIRR sorry I don’t have the reputation to give pic, but the traceback is “string index out of range” on the “if guess==game_word[0] line

Comment: `random.choice( ['A','B','C'] )` gives you one random element of this list - shortens your `word_get()`

Comment: You never called `word_gen()` so you have nothing in it...

Comment: I think the issue is the guess_compare() function doesn’t know what guess and game_word are as described in the earlier two functions. But I don’t know how to fix that.

Comment: @PatrickArtner caking them doesn’t fix it though

Comment: Calling* it doesn’t

Comment: @user9211054, you are calling only `guess_compare()` and `game_word` is still an empty string, which is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

I would quit using the global vars, you tend to hide them by declaring the same named vars locally, presuming you set a global but its just the local one.

I have retructured some of your code so it should work without global variables:

```
import random

def word_gen():
    """Returns a ramdom choice word form a fixed list"""
    return random.choice(["hello", "test", "never"])  

def guesser():
   """Returns an input from the user - ask for 1 letter"""
   return input("give a letter...")

def guess_compare():
    """Main game loop for "guess my word character by character".

    Gets a random word. Asks for letters until the correct
    one is given. Prints out status messages regarding correctness
    of guesses. Stops when all characters were guessed correctly."""

    game_word = word_gen()

    soFar = ""   # for status-message, text correctly guessed so far
    for ch in game_word:        # check for every character in word
        while(guesser() != ch):   # guess until char is correct
            print("wrong")
        else:                     # finally, one more ch solved...
            soFar += ch
            print("you guessed correctly: " + soFar)
    print("you solved it!")     # finished


guess_compare()  # start the game
```

Using no globals might seem tougher, but it eleminates one source of error.

If you still want them, you need to declare that you want to use the global in your funcion:

---

**Some funcs with global variables:**

```
def myFunc():
    global myVar        # declare that we use the global here
    myVar += 20         # modifying the global one here
    print (myVar)

def myOtherFunc():
    myVar = "something"   # this is just local , not the global one
    print (myVar)

myVar = 25
print ("myVar: ", myVar)

myFunc()
print ("after myFunc: ", myVar)

myOtherFunc()
print ("after myOtherFunc: ", myVar)
```

Output:

```
myVar:  25
45
after myFunc:  45
something
after myOtherFunc:  45
```

Comment: Okay thanks so much! Interested to figure out the variable assignment rules etc too so will play around too. Thanks!!

Comment: @user9211054 Added example for `global` variables

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have never assigned  game_word with word_gen(). You also have to call your guesser function first.

Try this this on the last line of your code:

```
guesser()
game_word = word_gen()
guess_compare()
```

Comment: Okay none of these is working. Thanks for the help, I’ll play around a bit and let you know what I find

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is that when first calling the function

```
    guess_compare()
```

Your variable game_word, is set to a value of "". Then, when you try to make the comparison, on this line

```
    if guess==game_word[0]:
```

game_word[0] will through an error, as the game_word has a length of 0, so there is no value, and the index "0" will be out of range.

I'm not sure if part of the code is missing, but just by looking at the code above, it seems like that would be the error.

To solve this, you could check at the start of the function whether or not game_word has a some value, and therefore can be indexed. Like this.

```
    def guess_compare():
        if game_word == "": 
            return # this will end the function here. 

        if guess==game_word[0]:
            print("correct")
        else:
            print("wrong")
```

Hope this helps :)